# pdo binding not giving value

Tags: php, pdo

the :cat_id has  a value of nine and :tlk_id  has a value of 3 if i enter them manually it will run with desired result but after binding them it gives me a row count of zero

```
<?

   $sql = ("
       SELECT
           p.post_id as sn,
           p.subject,
           p.username,
           COUNT(thread_id)-1 AS responses,
           MAX(DATE_FORMAT(p.date_posted,'%e-%b-%y %l:  %i    %p')) AS first,
           MAX(DATE_FORMAT(t.date_posted,'%e-%b-%y %l:%i %p')) AS last
       FROM
           posts AS p
       INNER JOIN
           threads AS t 
       USING 
           (post_id) 
       INNER JOIN 
           register AS u 
       ON
           p.username = u.username
       WHERE 
           t.category_id =:cat_id
       AND
           p.category_id =:cat_id
       AND
           t.forum_id = :tlk_id
       AND
           p.forum_id = :tlk_id
       GROUP BY
           (t.post_id)
       ORDER BY
           last DESC
       LIMIT $start,$display
    ");

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(':tlk_id',$tlk_id);
    $sth->bindParam(':cat_id',$cat_id);

    $r =  $sth->execute();
    $count = $sth->rowCount();
    echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `display_errors` turned on?  You may be getting a bunch of warnings if the statement failed to prepare.  `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: it gives me this error Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() [pdostatement.bindparam]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\uni\forum\viewposts.php on line 95     line  95 is           $sth->bindParam(':cat_id',$cat_id);

Comment: Doesn't it have a problem with `=:`? Doesn't it require a space?

Comment: @Vyktor I was just going to suggest that. I'm surprised it would be a problem, but that is the thing that stands out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error:

> Invalid parameter number: parameter ...

You can see that not all the parameters are processed. So maybe you can add 4 parameters in this case:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        .....
       WHERE 
           t.category_id =:cat_id_1
       AND
           p.category_id =:cat_id_2
       AND
           t.forum_id = :tlk_id_1
       AND
           p.forum_id = :tlk_id_2
      ....
    ";

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(':tlk_id_1',$tlk_id);
    $sth->bindParam(':tlk_id_2',$tlk_id);
    $sth->bindParam(':cat_id_1',$cat_id);
    $sth->bindParam(':cat_id_2',$cat_id);
```

Comment: What would be a point of using named parameters if you wouldn't be able to reuse them? (Okay it's more readable, but having the same thing 4 times with 4 different names is just mess)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
$tlk_id = 3;
$cat_id = 9;

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(':tlk_id',$tlk_id);
$sth->bindParam(':cat_id',$cat_id);
```

I'm assigning the values to a variable because bindParam expects a reference as a second parameter.

Comment: they are generated from sessions and they have their vaue